# Place detection api doesn't work on avd

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I'm working on Android with the `Google Places API`.
I'm having problems when running the PlaceDetectionApi's getCurrentPlace-method. The `PlaceLikelihoodBuffer` I get in the `resultcallback` of the method is empty, when I print the `errorstatus` in my logcat, it say's the errorcodenumber is 13 and in the logcat, I can also read the line "D/`PlaceInferenceEngine: No place inference engine is running, returning null"`.
I'm running this in an AVD on my emulator, unfortunately I can't test it on a real device in the moment.
So, the question is: what is this place inference engine and how can I get it running on my AVD?

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
public void getCurrentPosition(int requestCode) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    requestCode);
        } else {
            if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_GET_CURRENT_POSITION) {
                PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(client, new PlaceFilter());
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
                        System.out.println("inside callback...");
                        Status status = placeLikelihoods.getStatus();
                        System.out.println(status.isSuccess());
                        System.out.println(status.getStatusCode());
                        System.out.println(status.getStatusMessage());
                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods) {
                            Place place = placeLikelihood.getPlace();
                            System.out.println("possible place: " + place.getAddress());
                        }
                        placeLikelihoods.release();
                    }
                });
            }
         }
}
```

The result in my logcat is:

```
06-19 14:39:33.436 1865-2848/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/PlaceInferenceEngine: No place inference engine is running, returning null
06-19 14:39:33.437 1865-2284/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Places: getLastLocation returned null. Falling back to location updates
06-19 14:39:33.621 1865-2148/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
06-19 14:39:43.478 1865-2284/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Places: Timed out waiting for a location for getCurrentPlace
06-19 14:39:43.500 2760-2760/com.example.kevin.mapproject I/System.out: inside callback...
06-19 14:39:43.500 2760-2760/com.example.kevin.mapproject I/System.out: false
06-19 14:39:43.500 2760-2760/com.example.kevin.mapproject I/System.out: 13
06-19 14:39:43.500 2760-2760/com.example.kevin.mapproject I/System.out: ERROR
```

Comment: test on real device....

Comment: ok, i'll try this as soon as possible. Nevertheless: is it even possible to retrieve the current position on avd? i just tried out LocationManager as an alternative, it also doesn't work

Comment: As far I know, you can send lat-long to your emulator manually (not sure if there is any method to retrieve it automatically from your computer). In eclipse, start your emulator and then - Window > Open Perspective > DDMS > Emulator Control > type a lat-long > Send.

Comment: alright, thank you very much Sudip :) your suggestion was right, you have to provide mock data for the emulator, it is also written in the very end of this developer guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html